# Что такое строго типизированный класс?

Tags: .net

Что такое строго типизированный класс?

Answer (score 1):

Строго типизированным может быть язык. Возможно, под строго типизированным классом где-то подразумевался Generic-класс.

Answer (score 0):

[Типы](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173104.aspx) (Руководство по программированию на C#):

> C# является строго типизированным языком. Каждая переменная и константа имеет тип, как и каждое выражение, результатом вычисления которого является значение. Каждая сигнатура метода задает тип для каждого входного параметра и для возвращаемого значения.

Answer (score 0):

Понятие строгой типизации — это [неформальное понятие](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing), говорящее о сравнительной выразительности *системы типов* языка. Строгого общепринятого определения строгой типизации не существует.

Для C# система типов *достаточно* богата, чтобы выразить отношения между *данными* (объектно-ориентированный язык), но не слишком сильна, когда речь заходит об отношениях между *типами*. Например, в ней нельзя выразить условие «всякий подтип *S* данного типа *T* имеет метод *X*, принимающий аргумент типа *S*». (Например, условие «объекты типа можно сравнивать с другими объектами того же типа».)

Тем не менее, язык C# в большей своей части *типобезопасен*: тип выражения, определённый во время компиляции, гарантирован статическим анализом и библиотекой времени выполнения. Исключениями являются явные операции преобразования типа и специальный тип `dynamic` (которые могут привести к выбрасыванию исключения), а также `unsafe`-код, который может привести к компроментации типобезопасности.

---

Понятия же строго типизированного класса вовсе не существует.